# How to iterate over previous rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns: id (non-unique id), X (categories) and Y (categories). (I don't have a dataset to share yet. I'll try to replicate what I have using a smaller dataset and edit as soon as possible)

I ran a for loop on a very small subset and based on those results it might take over 4 hours to run this code. I'm looking for a faster way to do this task using pandas (maybe using iterrows, like iterating over previous rows within apply)

For each row I check

1. whether the current X matches any of previous Xs (check_X = X[:row] == X[row])
2. whether the current Y matches any of previous Ys (check_Y = Y[:row] == Y[row])
3. whether the current id does not match any of previous ids (check_id = id[:row] != id[row])

if sum(check_X & check_Y & check_id)>0: then append 1 to the array
else: append 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are probably looking for `duplicated`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'X': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
                   'Y': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

df['dup'] = ~df[df.duplicated(['X', 'Y'])].duplicated('id', keep=False).loc[lambda x: ~x]
df['dup'] = df['dup'].fillna(False).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
   id  X  Y  dup
0   0  1  2    0
1   0  1  2    0
2   0  2  2    0
3   1  1  2    1
4   0  1  2    0
```

**Update**

`X` and `Y` should be checked separately:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
                   'X': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'Y': [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})

df['dup'] = np.where(df['X'].duplicated() & df['Y'].duplicated() & ~df['id'].duplicated(), 1, 0)
print(df)

# Output
   id  X  Y  dup
0   0  0  0    0
1   1  1  2    0
2   1  1  2    0
3   2  1  2    1
4   2  1  2    0
5   3  1  2    1
6   4  1  2    1
```

Comment: I don't think this would work in my case. X and Y should match but id should not match.

Comment: @animus. I updated my answer. Please can you check it? I made a first pass to check X and Y and a second pass to check ID.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply but I think the website was down on Friday. I think this is right. Thank you.

Comment: I thought it was right looking at the code but when I tried it on my dataset I was getting more results (ones) than expected. I found that there's an overlap between this and df.duplicated(['X', 'Y', 'id']) (which shouldn't be)

Comment: Can you provide a sample for a such case, please?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1, 1, 2, 2, 3,4],
                   'X': [0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1],
                   'Y': [0,2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2]})

try running the code for this data

Comment: just in case you're confused, I want to know if any of the previous ids have the same combination of X and Y.

Comment: No. they are two parts of the same thing.

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample?

Comment: expected output = 0,0,0,1,0,1,1 (ideal) or 0,0,0,1,1,1,1 (I can work with this too)

Comment: df['dup'] = np.where(df[['X', 'Y']].duplicated() & ~df['X', 'Y', 'id'].duplicated(), 1, 0)

Comment: Sorry bad copy/paste. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** answer from @Corralien using `duplicates()` will likely be much faster and the best answer for this specific problem. However, apply is more flexible if you have different things to check.

You could do it with `iterrows()` or `apply()`. As far as I know `apply()` is faster:

```
check_id, check_x, check_y = set(), set(), set()

def apply_func(row):
    global check_id, check_x, check_y
    if row["id"] not in check_id and row['x'] in check_x and row['y'] in check_y:
        row['duplicate'] = 1
    else:
        row['duplicate'] = 0
    check_id.add(row['id'])
    check_x.add(row['x'])
    check_y.add(row['y'])
    return row

df.apply(apply_func, axis=1)
```

With iterrows():

```
check_id, check_x, check_y = set(), set(), set()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["id"] not in check_id and row['x'] in check_x and row['y'] in check_y:
        df.loc[i, 'duplicate'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'duplicate'] = 0
    check_id.add(row['id'])
    check_x.add(row['x'])
    check_y.add(row['y'])
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply but I think the website was down on Friday. 
This is not what I want but I wrote something similar already using apply and global functions. It's pretty slow.